# I've written a newsletter subscriprion in php based on a script i had for a mail form, but $_Post is not working

Tags: php, forms, email, newsletter

I only get empty mails from the server...

This is the code:

```
    <?php
    $field_email = $_POST['sub-email'];

    $mail_to = 'alex.dapunt@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Newsletter Subscriprion '.$field_email;

    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert("We'll notify you as soon the new website is online.");
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Subscription failed. Please, send an email to alex.dapunt@gmail.com');
        // window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

and this the html:

```
  <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" data-scroll-reveal="wait 0.5s, then enter bottom and move 20px over 1s">
        <div class="lj-block-center">
          <input type="text" value="mail" name="sub-email" id="mail" placeholder="Enter your e-mail">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        </div>
      </form>
```

I really don't get why it is not working. But I have to say that I'm a newbie in PHP

Comment: What is empty, the subject, the body, or both?

Comment: it didn't pass the mail from the form to subject and body

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line

```
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
```

you used concatenation instead of assigning the value.

This is your code with my modifications

```
<?php
$field_email = $_POST['sub-email'];

$mail_to = 'alex.dapunt@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Newsletter Subscriprion '.$field_email;

$body_message = 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


if ($mail_status) {
  echo '
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert("We\'ll notify you as soon the new website is online.");
        window.location = \'index.html\';
    </script>';
}
else {
  echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert(\'Subscription failed. Please, send an email to alex.dapunt@gmail.com\');
    // window.location = \'contact_page.html\';
</script>';}?>
```

but i have to say that if this is just an example it's ok but if you'r gonna use it in your site you have to do some input validation.

Comment: Neither this is working :(
The validation is written with javascript. This was a lot easier for me.

Comment: @user3481351 Maybe you've something wrong with your server config because i tried it 3 times before i post